# SSH connection with password and certificate with Jenkins

Tags: ssh, jenkins, passwords, certificate

In our servers, we configured 2 types of authentication to ssh conections. We need a user with password and ssh certificate (tipical id_rsa.key).

We use Jenkins, and i want connect to this servers with "publish over ssh" plugin, but i don't know the way to make this connection.

I know that i can make this conection with a "Send files or execute commands over ssh", but i would prefer to use the plugin.

Anyone knows a possible method?

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, we didn't found any good answer with plugins.

We used a ssh command like this:

`sshpass -p '$(pass)' ssh -T -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -i <certificate-path> $user@$ip_machine`